# Custom Knockout binding with multiple inputs, one of which is contains an indexed array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[Here is an example of my problem on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/67TyP/3/)

I want to create a custom binding that takes two inputs. This can be done by passing an array of values to the binding. For instance, this binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.whatever = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var args = valueAccessor();
        element.innerHTML = args[0] + " " + args[1];
    }
};
```

Will take two inputs and concatenate them with a space in between. So then something like `<p data-bind="whatever: ['First', 'Second']"></p>` will display as `<p>First Second</p>`.

This works with variables too. So if I have some data in a view model:

```
var vm = {
    category: "Category",
    people: [
        {name:  "Bob"},
        {name:  "Ann"}
    ]
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I can do something like:

```
<p data-bind="whatever: [category, 'blah blah blah']"></p>
```

and it will display:

```
<p>Category blah blah blah</p>
```

My problem arises when I want to pass a nested variable to my binding. Something like this:

```
<p data-bind="whatever: [people[0].name, 'blah blah blah']"></p>
```

I want it to display `<p>Bob blah blah blah</p>`, but instead I get this error message:

**Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list; Bindings value: whatever: [people[0].name, 'blah blah blah']**

(Once again, [here's a link to this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67TyP/3/).)

This seems pretty strange, as if it's getting confused and thinking that the `[0]` is another list rather than an index on `people`. Any ideas why this happens or how to fix the problem?

I'm not very experienced with Knockout so it is very probable that I'm doing things horribly wrong. For instance, I'm struggling to even find examples online of people creating custom bindings that take multiple inputs directly from the template (is this something that just shouldn't be done for some reason?).

Comment: This is a bug/limitation of the KO binding parsing. Here is the same or a very similar issue on [Github](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/694). There is no problem to use arrays as parameter in custom bindings. The problem is that you try to build up the parameter array inside the binding expression. If you have any complex logic like `people[0].name` then it should be done in the viewmodel and not in the binding itself: http://jsfiddle.net/q7mgV/

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure of the problem aside from passing an array seems to cause the issue.   I replaced with named params and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/37Py6/

Note also I used the

```
ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(...)
```

, so as to not do DOM manipulation is knockout code.

Answer (score 1):

Also works if you wrap it up with a function:
http://jsfiddle.net/67TyP/7/

```
<p data-bind="whatever: function(){ return [people[0].name, 'blah blah blah']}() "></p>
```